# Referring to a header range even after columns are inserted

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet as illustrated below:
[image].

The button with the green text allows me to expand and collapse columns A:F, according to the macro below.

The problem is that the macro refers specifically to columns `A:F`. If I were to insert an additional column under my main column header ("Läkemedelsinformation"), I would still only be able to collapse/expand columns A:F, unless I edit the code manually.

How do I go about making the macro detect the relevant columns dynamically based on the main column header?

```
Public Sub LKMinfo()
 Dim SH As Worksheet
 Dim Rng As Range
 Dim obj As Variant
 Dim BTN As Button
 Dim iLen As Long
 Const myColumns As String = "A:F"               '<<===== Change
 Const släkemedelsinformation As String = "Läkemedelsinformation"                       '<<===== Change
 Const sHidden As String = " Hidden"
 Const sVisible As String = " Visible"

 Set SH = ActiveSheet
 Set BTN = SH.Buttons(Application.Caller)
 Set Rng = SH.Columns(myColumns)
 With Rng.EntireColumn
     .Hidden = Not .Hidden
     If .Hidden Then
     iLen = Len(sHidden) + Len(släkemedelsinformation)
         BTN.Characters.Text = släkemedelsinformation & " Hidden"
         With BTN.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=iLen).Font
             .Name = "Arial"
             .FontStyle = "Bold"
             .Size = 10
             .ColorIndex = 3  '\\ RED
         End With
     Else
     iLen = Len(sVisible) + Len(släkemedelsinformation)
     BTN.Characters.Text = släkemedelsinformation & " Visible"
         With BTN.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=iLen).Font
             .Name = "Arial"
             .FontStyle = "Bold"
             .Size = 10
             .ColorIndex = 4  '\\ GREEN
         End With
     End If
 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Loop the cells in row 3 and stop at the first one that doesn't contain text?

Comment: By Dynamic column I understand all the column headers that contains something, you may want to do something like `Dim startCell As Range

Set startCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")
''this should be the start cell for your workbook, you may have to change the sheet name and range details

Range(startCell, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the columns using the [`.Find` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), passing in the column header name.

I would advise to set the `.Find` to a range variable.

```
Dim col_header1 As Range, col_header2 As Range

Set col_header1 = Columns("A:Z").Find("header_name1")
Set col_header2 = Columns("A:Z").Find("header_name2")
```

You can then assess if you were successful in finding all of the headers. If all of the headers were found, you can assign the column number values and use them in your code.

```
If Not col_header1 Is Nothing And _
   Not col_header2 Is Nothing Then

    col_number1 = col_header1.Column
    col_number2 = col_header2.Column

Else

    MsgBox ("One or more of the columns were not found!")
    Exit Sub

End If
```

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but it is worth noting that any change to the header text will require maintenance of the code, else it will break.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how I include your code into my code? I am still very new with VBA...

Comment: Very true @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - it's a more useful technique for when opening workbooks which contain data sets without a static structure, although constant header names.

Answer (score 1):

Just name your range.

In the example below, I have three headers, and named that range "Barn" using the Name Box (that little field to the left of the function bar). For more help with this, see e.g. [this video](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) or any of great many found using a simple web search.

[image]

If I then insert a column after column B, the named range "Barn" just expands to include it. This is illustrated when I select the "Barn" range using the Name Box drop-down:

[image]

You can refer to this range in VBA as follows:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("Barn")

With r.EntireColumn
    '... do stuff
```

So you don't need to specify which columns Range `r` should refer to anymore (e.g. A to F — don't need to specify that). You just say that `r` refers to the range named "Barn".

Comment: Thank you for helping but I am still not sure how I should rearrange the original code to get the desired results...

Comment: Okay... do you have a specific question about that? I gave you a code snippet. I suggest you make an attempt at massaging it into your code. If you run into problems. ask a question. You'll never learn if you don't try.

Comment: If I name the range of columns as "mycolumns" and replace (Const myColumns As String = "A:F") by (Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("mycolumns"), I can't make the code work because I have other statements that must be edited to account for the fact that the column is no longer constant. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Again, I suggest you post a question describing that specific new problem.